# Accessing Named Credentials' data in apex

Tags: apex, webservices, oauth2, callout, authentication

Is there a way of accessing the data (exact fields) stored in Spring 15' `Named Credentials` from apex? For example the username, password and endpoint link fields? And I don't mean for the callout, but for other purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Named Credentials** to create an End point URL with necessary parameters. For example, if this is is your URL:

```
https://www.someendpointurl.com?param1=named&param2=credentials
```

In Apex, You can access this URL like this:

```
request.setEndpoint('callout:EndPointURL');
```

Where, *EndPointURL* is the Name of the Named Credentials.

**Benefits of using Named Credentials:**

- Authentication is done by Salesforce and you need not to worry about that.
- No need to create a Remote Site Setting if using a Named Credential.
- Callout is easier to maintain. No hard coding involved.
- If are also using Sandboxes for callout, just create the Named Credentials with the same name and save different URL.

Hope this helps..!!

But actually accessing the data stored in the Named Credentials fields (e.g. as String) is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've read this and it was precisely the reason why I wanted to use it. But I also need to access the fields stored in the object. For other purposes than callouts.

Comment: @JaKu - So, you want to access other fields of Named Credentials?

Comment: I wouldn't call them 'other' fields. I would like to access the values in the fields that are stored there. I don't think it is possible. I think that the use of the object is write-use, not write-read-use.

Comment: Yes, that's not possible.

Comment: How do you set the parameters in the endpoint URL? @the_phantom

Comment: @Monish: Like this - 
request.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path?key=value');

Comment: Thanks, @the_phantom Got the hiccups. We cannot use the username and password merge fields in the endpoint. We need to add it in either header or body.

Comment: @Monish Well, you should always pass username, password or token in the Authorization http header key. Passing credentials as url parameter is not safe.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use [Merge Fields for Apex Callouts That Use Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm). This won't explicitly give you access to the data from the named credential in Apex, but it will allow you to alter how it is used in any callout.

For example, you could define custom request headers:

```
// non-standard authentication
req.setHeader('X-Username', '{!$Credential.UserName}');
req.setHeader('X-Password', '{!$Credential.Password}');
```

Or you could include the credentials in the request body:

```
req.setBody('UserName:{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Username)}')
req.setBody('Password:{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}')
```

Note that there is a special case in a request body where you can use the `HTMLENCODE` formula function to escape special characters.

Comment: the `$Credential` merge fields return the username and password of the current running user. If I want to store username and password in a named credential and use them in non-standard authorization headers for my HTTP request, this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

No way to get username and password from Named Credential. But you can SOQL [NamedCredential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_namedcredential.htm) object. I then SOQL [AuthProvider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_authprovider.htm) (this one was usefull particularly for me) for some more details.

Comment: Does this let you get to the values? Can you show an example of the process?

Comment: You can get values from fields that are present in the object. The same as any other SObject. You are asking about Username/Password - no, these data is not accessible.