# Authorize Oauth in Named Credentials via Apex Code

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials

Bit of an outlier type question here, but we have an Apex application that needs to access 50 or so peoples Google Calendar, and we have tested it with Named Credentials and OAuth 2, and it works quite well. The issue arises when we try and set up all 50 named credentials for these representatives, as we don't want to allow them access to the Named Credentials to set this up themselves due to security issues.

Is there any way possible we can set up something in Apex to authorize a Named Credential that our reps can access from a web portal we set up? Where they click a button to authorize a Named Credential, and it returns back the Google OAuth screen to them? I cant find a ton of information on Named Credentials, the only one I can find that says this isnt possible was from [2015](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79945/accessing-named-credentials-data-in-apex), so I was wondering if things had changed.

Thanks so much

Comment: You might be able to do this in the upcoming Winter 23 release: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_other_custom_named_credentials.htm&type=5&release=240